# Does Cortana Skill support login with Azure AD B2C account?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, botframework, azure-ad-b2c, cortana-skills-kit

Does Cortana Skill support login with Azure AD B2C account? I have created a tenant on azure and done all configuration like

1. setting sign-in or sign-up policy
2. adding new application

[image]

3. setting connected service for cortana skill

[image]

Authorization URL:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/9d380b75-4f64-426c-987c-77dd98a32a10b/B2C_1_SiUpIn/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

Token URL:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/9d380b75-4f64-426c-987c-77dd98a32a10b/B2C_1_SiUpIn/oauth2/v2.0/token

But my skill still couldn't work with that, I always saw the following error message when I tried to invoke it. Anyone has idea?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Cortana requires an MSA account.  The same MSA account must be used both for registering the bot in the [dev portal](https://dev.botframework.com/) and the account you are logged into Cortana with.  More info can be found here [testing Cortana basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/debug-bots-cortana-skill-invoke) also [How to change the account you have logged into Cortana with](https://www.howtogeek.com/283814/how-to-use-cortana-with-a-local-user-account-in-windows-10/)

Comment: I know cortana is required to login with MSA account, but my question is how about the skill with connected account that used AAD B2C? For example, Dominos Pizza skill requires user sign-in their pizza service before it start the conversasion. I want to do the exact same thing. I used AAD B2C as my oauth server but it seems doesn't work.  https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/P4063

Comment: Apologies, I totally misunderstood what you were asking.  take a look at [AuthBot](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/authbot) and [BotAuth](https://github.com/richdizz/BotAuth)  they should help you get started in the right direction at least

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You seemed still misunderstood my question. As I said,  I tried to configure Cortana's Connected Account feature with my AAD B2C but it didn't work.